# Passing Checkbox state from one page to another

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 webpages, Page A and Page B, Page A have links(link 1 and link 2) and page B have checkboxes(checkbox 1 and checkbox 2). When i click on the link 1 on page A, it will change to page B with the checkbox 1 in page B to be checked vice versa. mainly for html5 and/or jquery

Thanks

forget to show example coding..
this is what i tried

Page A

```
<a href="pageb.html#check1" checked>Link to check Checkbox1</a> 


<a href="pageb.html#check2" checked > Link to Check Checkbox2</a>
```

Page B

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<Label for="checkbox1>CheckBox1</label>


<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">

<Label for="checkbox2>CheckBox2</label>
```

Comment: You could use jQuery for reading and setting the checkbox, but it seems like you just need [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), it's very [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use html5, localStorage might help you. Just save the state of your checkbox in page A with localStorage.setItem("pageAcheck","true") and then get it at the second page with localStorage.get item("page a check")

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/01yw7xoy/)

page A

```
<input id="cA" type="checkbox" />A

$("#cA").change(function (event) {
    alert($("#cA").is(":checked"));
    localStorage.setItem("cA",$("#cA").is(":checked"));
});
```

page B

```
<input id="cAB" type="checkbox" />B
// in the second page on load
$(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cA") == "true")
        $("#cB").prop("checked","true")
});
```

Comment: could you show an example?? i cant seem to get it right.. maybe i'm doing it wrong... thanks in advance

Comment: just added example for you (above)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to combine jQuery with `[localStorage][1]` you could do this:

On PageA.html:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('input[name=check]').on('change', function() {
      window.localStorage.setItem('pageACheck', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
  });
</script>
<input type='checkbox' name='check'/> Check
```

Then on PageB.html you can have this code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('input[name=check]').attr("checked", window.localStorage.getItem('pageACheck'));
  });
</script>
<input type='checkbox' name='check'/> Check
```

What the code in `PageA.html` is doing is binding the change event of a checkbox to a callback which stores the changed value.  Then in a DOM Ready callback the code in `PageB.html` is taking the stored value and setting the checkbox, in effect, carrying over the value between pages.

Comment: Both uses checkbox inputs? but what i'm looking for is page only have links in other words using link to check the checkboxes on the other page